# Room with Dagger in Kotlin: Dao is null, when injecting into a class

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2, android-room

I'm just getting familiar with the new Room library, and I came through an annoying problem. I have a `UserRepository` class, which does the data loading from network and from local storage depending on multiple factors. When I want to inject the Dao object from the database, I get this error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull

Here are the parts of the code, what may cause this error

ApplicationModule

```
    @Module
class ApplicationModule(val application: CustomApplication) {
    private val BASE_URL = "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/"

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideAppContext() : Context = application

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideRetrofit(): Retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(Gson()))
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .build()

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideUserRepository(retrofit: Retrofit, database: AppDatabase) =
            UserRepository(
                    retrofit.create(UserService::class.java),
                    retrofit.create(QuestionService::class.java),
                    database.userDao())

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideDatabase(context: Context)
            = Room.databaseBuilder(context, AppDatabase::class.java, "db-name").build()
}
```

UserDao

```
@Dao
interface UserDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM user")
    fun getAllUsers() : Flowable<List<User>>

    @Insert
    fun insertAll(users: List<User>)
}
```

AppDatabase

```
@Database(entities = arrayOf(User::class), version = 1)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun userDao() : UserDao
}
```

Do anybody have an idea why `database.userDao()` could be null? Do I need to do additional initialization before I request it from the database? I can't find info about this anywhere